# Edit Adobe PDF programmatically using SDK, without opening file

Tags: c#, pdf, adobe

I can do what I intended, which is to open 2 PDFs, merge the first into the second, then save.

```
AcroAVDoc avFrom = new AcroAVDocClass();
AcroAVDoc avTo = new AcroAVDocClass();

AcroPDDoc pdFrom;
AcroPDDoc pdTo;

if (avFrom.Open (fileinfo.FullName, ""))
{
    pdFrom = (AcroPDDoc)avFrom.GetPDDoc();

    if (avTo.Open(combinedFullPath, ""))
    {
        pdTo = (AcroPDDoc)avTo.GetPDDoc();

        pdTo.InsertPages(pdTo.GetNumPages() - 1, pdFrom, 0, pdFrom.GetNumPages(), 0);
        pdTo.Save(1, combinedFullPath);
        Adobe.CloseAllDocs();
    }
    else
    {
        Debug.Write("Failed to open combined pdf to merge with: " + CaseNo);
    }
}
```

The problem is that Adobe window opens and slows everything down as I'm looping this thousands of times.

Does anyone know how to keep all this in code?

Comment: Look at using a library such as iTextSharp http://sourceforge.net/projects/itextsharp/

Comment: or [pdfium.net sdk](http://pdfium.patagames.com/Help/html/4de6ffc2-d160-4198-ab8c-ed479e9bdf96.htm) based on chrome's pdfium project

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
AcroPDDoc pdFrom = new AcroPDDoc();
AcroPDDoc pdTo = new AcroPDDoc();

if (pdFrom.Open (fileinfo.FullName))
{

    if (pdTo.Open(combinedFullPath))
    {

        pdTo.InsertPages(pdTo.GetNumPages() - 1, pdFrom, 0, pdFrom.GetNumPages(), 0);
        pdTo.Save(1, combinedFullPath);
        pdFrom.Close();
        pdTo.Close();
    }
    else
    {
        pdFrom.Close();
        Debug.Write("Failed to open combined pdf to merge with: " + CaseNo);
    }
}

}
```